# How to display Main Form once Controls are Loaded

Tags: c#, winforms, splash-screen

I am creating a simple program that has a splash screen that displays for 3 seconds, following the splash screen, my main form loads. However, when my main form loads, it will be in the process of loading all my controls (I have 36 buttons on my page... using them for a roulette table). So for the first 1-2 seconds of my main form being displayed, it is loading all these buttons and looks kind of ugly. How do I go about loading this form during the 3 second time of my splash screen or any other ways? Thanks

---

```
for (i = 0; i < 36; i++) 
{ int j, k; j = i % 3; k = i / 3; 
  button[i] = new Label(); 
  button[i].Location = new Point(80 + (41*j), 64 + (20*k)); 
  button[i].Cursor = Cursors.Hand; 
  etc etc. 
}
```

Comment: for (i = 0; i < 36; i++)
            {
                int j, k;

                j = i % 3;
                k = i / 3;
                

                button[i] = new Label();
                button[i].Location = new Point(80 + (41*j), 64 + (20*k));
                button[i].Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
                etc etc.
            }

Comment: and it basically looks like the form when loaded will scramble to draw all these buttons dynamically at start up, but I just simply want them drawn and then display the main form, so it isn't all ugly looking.

Comment: Nick - you should edit your question with this new information - of nothing else you'll get formatting and syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't loading them, you are seeing the time needed just to paint the buttons.  You can easily double-check this: minimize the form and restore it.  This taking 2 seconds is rather on the high end, maybe it just feels that way or you've got very underpowered hardware.  Having 36 buttons does put you close to being able to observe the painting, especially when they have an Image.  Do make sure the images you put on the button are sized right, having to rescale them to fit the button is expensive and eats into the painting time.

A splash screen isn't going to solve this problem unless you run this on Vista or Win7 with Aero enabled.  You can hide it somewhat with the Opacity property, increasing from 0 to 0.99 with a timer.  A true fix is to not use buttons but just draw the roulette table in the form's OnPaint() method override.  You'll however have to then add the code to do mouse hit testing.

A Q&D fix is to double-buffer the entire form, rendering into an off-screen bitmap then getting the result blitted to the screen.  That doesn't speed up the painting, it just isn't noticeable anymore.  Paste this code into your form class to use the built-in support for this in Windows XP and up:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
  get {
    CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
    cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
    return cp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Well the double buffer definitely helped a lot. It is something I can deal with. Basically what it looks like now is that iterates through the 36 buttons very quickly to make them all transparent.